# WiX CustomAction: How to get bootstrapper location from msi

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

For a custom action I need the location of the installers bootstrapper path.

`session["SourceDir"]` gives me:

`C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{67668D1E-88B7-4D10-B1B5-98D42AA088E5}\...`

but my setup during my test is located in `C:\Temp` which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass bootstrapper variable into MSI.

The variables you can pass: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html

This seems what you want: **WixBundleOriginalSource** - gets the source path from where the bundle originally ran.

How can you pass it from the bootstrapper:

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile='ProductSetup.msi' DisplayInternalUI='yes'>
   <MsiProperty Name='CONFIGFILELOCATION' Value='[WixBundleOriginalSource]' />
</MsiPackage>
```

This will make `CONFIGFILELOCATION` property available in your `ProductSetup.msi` file, which you then can access.

Comment: Using `session[OriginalDatabase]` gives me `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8CB19C9C-216F-40DA-B9FA-55D1735F6A67}v1.0.1.0\Setup X1-netfabb.msi` not `C:\Temp\Setup.exe`  To clarify: `X1-netabb.msi` is part of my bootstrapper project and calls the custom action. `Setup.exe`is the Bootstrapper.